# Saving a kdb+ "unmappable" table to disk

Tags: kdb, kbd-rdb

I have a table in my *rdb* (running the standard r.q) that includes a nested list of floats of the form:

```
(((1.a 1.b);(2.a 2.b);...;(N.a N.b));((N+1.a N+1.b);...;(N+X.a N+X.b)))
```

When `.u.end` is called I get an "unmappable error".

Is there anyway to save deeply nested data to an *hdb*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually save these tables using the following steps:

```
q)t:([] a:1 2 3; f:(1 2.0;(3 4.;5 6.); 7. 8.))
q)t
a f
---------
1 1   2
2 3 4 5 6
3 7   8
q)`:t/ set t
k){$[@x;.[x;();:;y];-19!((,y),x)]}
'type
q.q))
q.q))\
q)
```

Fails as nested type.

```
q)`:t/ set select a from t
`:t/
q)`:t/.d set `a`f
`:t/.d
q)`:t/f set t`f
`:t/f
q)\l .
q)t
a f
---------
1 1   2
2 3 4 5 6
3 7   8
```

Succeeds but if you compare access speed with non-nested data, you will see access is very slow.

It is probably not built-in behaviour to prevent users saving in this format without knowing the trade-offs.

Comment: I hear you on the tradeoffs, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to store indeterminately long lists on to a more structured table. Even if I capped it and wrote to explicit columns for every list element, there would be a ton of nulls across most entries.